# ansible identifying values in a list

Tags: list, ansible

The below code is attempting to find all the keys associated with the value HWIC-8A. I have tried a few different variations & I can't get the key to print, without doing something really long winded. As i'll be repeating this code with different values, i don't want to search each key/value pair individually within that list.

```
MODULES:
  Slot_0_SubSlot_0: HWIC-8A
  Slot_0_SubSlot_1: EHWIC-VA-DSL-M
  Slot_0_SubSlot_3: HWIC-8A
    
- name: Apply HWIC-8A Build
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.key }}"
  with_items: "{{ MODULES }}"
  when: "{{ item.value }} == HWIC-8A"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that's something for you:

```
--- 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    MODULES:
      Slot_0_SubSlot_0: HWIC-8A
      Slot_0_SubSlot_1: EHWIC-VA-DSL-M
      Slot_0_SubSlot_3: HWIC-8A
  tasks:
  - debug: var=MODULES
  - debug: msg="{{ MODULES | dict2items }}"
  - debug: msg="{{ MODULES | dict2items | selectattr('value','match','HWIC-8A') | map(attribute='key')| list }}"
```

Then if you would like to have multiple matches, you could solve it with an `MATCH` list:

```
--- 
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    MODULES:
      Slot_0_SubSlot_0: HWIC-8A
      Slot_0_SubSlot_1: EHWIC-VA-DSL-M
      Slot_0_SubSlot_3: HWIC-8A
      Slot_1_SubSlot_3: HWIC-8C
      Slot_1_SubSlot_2: HWIC-8C
    MATCH:
    - HWIC-8A
    - HWIC-8C
  tasks:
  - debug: 
      msg: "{{ MODULES | dict2items | selectattr('value','match',item) | map(attribute='key')| list }}"
    with_items: "{{ MATCH }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
Thursday 27 August 2020  15:08:10 +0200 (0:00:00.042)       0:00:02.037 ******* 
ok: [localhost] => (item=HWIC-8A) => {
    "msg": [
        "Slot_0_SubSlot_0",
        "Slot_0_SubSlot_3"
    ]
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=HWIC-8C) => {
    "msg": [
        "Slot_1_SubSlot_3",
        "Slot_1_SubSlot_2"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use use jinja templates to do it. Something like this:

```
  - name: Apply HWIC-8A Build
    debug:
      msg: '{% for m in MODULES %}{% if MODULES[m] == "HWIC-8A" %}{{ m }} {% endif %}{% endfor %}'
```

Which will give you this:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "Slot_0_SubSlot_0 Slot_0_SubSlot_3 "
}
```

There is probably a fancy way using filters as well.